# How to handle java.io.FileNotFoundException: in FileOutputStream?

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, fileoutputstream

I'm using Httpurlconnection and Fileoutstream to write/download file from Internet on android 12.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Download" + "/Customfolder");
if (!file.exists()) {
  boolean f = file.mkdir();
            }
File file1 = new File(file, "xyz.apk");
try {
      FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file1); //got below error from this line
    }catch (Exception e){
      Log.d("LOG",e+"");
                        }
```

Let's Say I download xyz.apk from abc.com site. When I download for it first time ,there is no error but after deleting xyz.apk from the custom folder and try to download it again, it show me error.

I even tried uninstalling and installing the app again but still gave error when I try to download xyz.apk

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/Customfolder/xyz.apk: open failed: EEXIST (File exists)
```

One thing I observed, let say I changed xyz.apk to xxyz.apk before download start than for the first time it will download file but if I again delete it from the custom folder and try to download again with renamed name xxyz.apk , it will throw same error as above.

Comment: You are doing nothing with the value of variable `f` or better with the return value of mkdir(). Check it and handle accordingly.

Comment: `but still gave error when I try to download xyz.apk` Nonsense. The exception has nothing to do with downloading a file but all with trying to create one.

Comment: You did not tell how you deleted the file. And why.

Comment: Variable f is needed,otherwise mkdir() doesn't work. I know this exception has nothing to do with it, that's why I mentioned in code which line is causing that exception. Just try to tell all the things I tried but didn't found the reason of that exception. I delete file manually. Just go to custom folder ,long press and delete

Comment: `Variable f is needed,otherwise mkdir() doesn't work.` Nonsense. Repeat: You are doing nothing with the value of variable f or better with the return value of mkdir(). Check it and handle accordingly. Adapt your code so we see that you do.

Comment: I can assure you, variable f have nothing to do with the exception,  it will be only true or false. So it will be more helpful, if you can provide me guidance for the exception I'm facing. I already specified which line caused that exception.

Comment: If the value is false you should stop. But you blindly continue and then you get an exception. Adapt your code.

Comment: Value of f is true and I still get that exception

Comment: Delete your custom folder. Adapt your code. Then try again. Also use file1.exists() and file1.canRead() and file1.canWrite() when possible before trying to open the stream. Adapt your code also here. Also tell Android version of used device.

Comment: Thanks for Your Time @blackapps. I tried using file1.exists() and file1.canRead() and file1.canWrite() for both the cases . when File is downloaded and when I get exception. In both cases values are same. I'm using Samsung F62 with android 12(API 31). Now I tried with Pixel XL API 31 emulator and in emulator it doesn't gave any exception. So I guess , it somehow my device fault as I also tried this code on API30 emulator and it doesn't gave any exception. If you think different , I would really like to hear your thoughts.